# How can I add a <span> element to a button rendered from WTForms?

Tags: html, css, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I am rendering a submit button in flask with WTForms like such:

forms.py:

```
class SignupForm(Form):
    submit = SubmitField("Register")
```

login.html:

```
<form method="POST" action="/register">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.submit(class_="primary-btn") }}
</form>
```

it renders a button that looks like this:

```
<input class="primary-btn" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Register">
```

[image]

But what I actually want is a button element, where I can add a  element so that I can add an arrow like such:

```
<button class="primary-btn">Register<span class="lnr lnr-arrow-right"></span></button>
```

[image]

I tried appending the span element to the String in the SubmitField, but this didn't work. It just raised Syntax errors.

Below you can see the pictures. I just want to add the arrow to the WTForm element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use `MarkUp`. [Documentation here](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/58904/flask.Markup)

```
import flask
submit_value = flask.Markup('<span class="lnr lnr-arrow-right"></span>')
submit_button = SubmitField(submit_value)
```

And in combination with your current code...

```
class SignupForm(Form):
    submit = submit_button
```

The `Markup` function is needed to tell your form it's safe to render without escaping.

If you'd rather avoid this, there are other ways. Typically, you don't need to specify the submit button in your python, as you don't normally need to input any useful data. I'd add the submit button HTML into the template manually like you said:

```
<button class="primary-btn" type="submit">Register<span class="lnr lnr-arrow-right"></span></button>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks, I'll try it. But one last question: Wouldn't adding the button manually break my CSRF protection? Isn't this why one should use WTForms?

Comment: No definitely not :) All CSRF does is add an extra field to your forms that gets sent with the form submission that then gets validated on the server. You could add as many HTML elements as you want. Although, I'd personally still avoid using plain HTML if you're doing the rest in python. It just makes more sense to keep it all in one place.

Comment: Well somehow I cannot make it work. Using Markup renders an input field like such: ```<input class="primary-btn" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="<span class=&quot;lnr lnr-arrow-right&quot;></span>">``` and when using the manual method, i get the error: method not allowed, even though POST is enabled?

Comment: @LGR Hmmm, that is strange. I've been trying to do some research for the last 30 minutes but I'm really not having much luck finding anything...

Comment: @A Friend I am sorry, the manual way worked now. I had an error in an if-statement.... Sorry for the confusion. So all in all: Markup does not work, as i can only change the String in the value, but adding the button manually works.

Comment: @LGR Ah, great! Glad you got it fixed in the end! I can see why the python isn't working, I just also don't know how to get around it either so I'm at a loss there! Oh well, if you got it working, that's all that matters in the end! Thanks for the update

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the `element:after` pseudo selector? with content: 'icon'.